# Pass the row nmbr, from the address written into the InputBox, to the "lngRow" variable for further use in the code?

Tags: excel, vba

Hey there StacOverflow friends.

Can you please help me to extract the row nmbr from the address written into the InputBox in my code.
From this line here: `sCell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8).Value`.

I'll need this row nmbr later, to write data, that I'm going to extract from the docx file, into the very same row in the very same sheet, that the cell pointed via InputBox is located.

I tried to extract this row nmbr using `MsgBox ActiveCell.Row` but using InputBox doesn't make the cell address written there, an active cell.

```
Sub update_custdb_from_id_number_to_the_right()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Dim wordApp As Word.Application            'it is assigned to button #2    'user-defined type not defined
   Dim wordDoc As Word.Document               '[0-9]{1;5}[ ]{1;2}/[0-9]{4}
   Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
   Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim Para As Word.Paragraph
   Dim wordRng As Word.Range
   Dim fullName As Word.Range
   Dim exclRng As Excel.Range
   Dim scndRng As Excel.Range
   Dim address As Excel.Range

   Dim pStart As Long
   Dim pEnd As Long
   Dim Length As Long
   Dim startPos As Long
   Dim endPos As Long
   Dim parNmbr As Long
   Dim x As Long
   Dim flag As Boolean
   Dim sCell As String
   Dim idNmbr As String
   Dim peselFromContract As String
   Dim lngRow As Long
   Dim textToFind1 As String

   'Assigning object variables and values
   Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")       'At its simplest, CreateObject creates an instance of an object,
   Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")     'whereas GetObject gets an existing instance of an object.
   Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument
   Set mySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   'Set MySheet = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   'Set scndRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:J40").Find("cena", , xlValues)
   Set scndRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
   textToFind1 = "ważnym do dnia"

   'sCell = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8)).Value              'sCell = Range(Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8)).Value
   ' Application-defined or object-defined error
   sCell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8).Value
   'MsgBox ActiveCell.Row
   sCell = Trim(sCell)
   Debug.Print sCell
   lngRow = 2
   x = 11
```

User @Naresh proposed adding `lngRow = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8).Row` line, which works fine for me, but has one major downside.

the downside is, that I need to input cell address 2 times. First to assign the `sCell` variable and second time, to assign row nmber using:

`lngRow = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8).Row` line.

What I need, is to automatically extract the row nmber from the address written into the InputBox, without interrupting code execution another time, only to input the same address for the 2nd time.

Comment: `ingRow = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8).Row`

Comment: ^^ to be honest, while the above works, you probably want to use a `Range` variable and `Set` it using that `Application.InputBox`. Then you can refer to `sCell.Row` for it's row. That would prevend a seperate inputbox asking for a value or column etc.

Comment: This line works for me, but the downside is, that I need to input cell address 2 times. First to assign the `sCell` variable and second time, to assign row nmber using `lngRow = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8).Row` line. What I need, is to automatically extract the row nmber from the address written into the InputBox, without interrupting code execution another time, only to input the same address for the 2nd time.

Comment: It's what I meant @michalroesler =)